# Isosceles right triangle and rhombus.

Tags: geometry

I have an isosceles right triangle with side $a$ with and two rhombus like this figure:

Try the image that we plot this figure. I need to find dependencies height $h'$ base and $\textit{angle}$ of $a$. 
How to proof that shape in the triangle is actually rhombus?

[image]

Comment: What is $a$? More generally, I'm not sure what the figure is representing exactly. I see two rhombi in a triangle, along with two extra segments. What are those extra segments?

Comment: $a$ is at least two sides of equal length. Those extra segments need me for plotting this shape.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having trouble understanding the figure. What are the rules for the construction? Maybe you could give a list of instructions on how to construct the figure.

Comment: First you claim that the shapes in the triangle are rhombi and then ask to prove this...

Comment: My intuition suggest that it's true. Do you have an argument that is not true?

Comment: I think you can rely on your intuition. Only you know how the shapes were constructed.

Comment: @Blabla Let us assume that the two rhombus-like figures are rhombi. It is clear that they have two common vertices, one of which lies on the base of the triangle.However, it is not clear whether the vertex of each rhombus opposite their common vertex on the base also lies on the sides of the triangle. Can you please clarify?

Comment: If you have two rhombi and want to find $h'$, I think the answer is $a = (2+\sqrt{2})h'$.